# How do I sort an associative array and split into two div's based on a value?

Tags: php, html, associative-array

I like to sort an associative array into two div's based on a value.

Here's what I have now:

```
 function showDivs($array) {
    /*
     * sort en group by
     */
    $luxury = false;
    $no_luxury = false;
    $return = '';
    while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) {

        if ($value["MinimumRate"] < 500) {
            if ($no_luxury === false) {
                $return .= '<div id="no_luxury" >';
            }
            $return .= $value['Description'] . " : " . $value["MinimumRate"] . "<br />";

            if ($no_luxury === false) {
                $return .='</div>';
                $no_luxury = true;
            }
        }

        if ($value["MinimumRate"] > 500) {
            if ($luxury === false) {
                $return .='<div id="luxury" >';
            }
            $return .= $value['Description'] . " : " . $value["MinimumRate"] . "<br />";

            if ($luxury === false) {
                $return .='</div>';
                $luxury = true;
            } 
        } 


    }
    return $return;
}
```

My code doesn't work correctly.

Comment: What its current wrong behavior is will save everyone 3 minutes .

Comment: if `MinimumRate` is 500 then it won't be in either div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div is being created and closed on the first item only. I think you meant to open it on start and close it in the end. Try this:

```
function showDivs($array) {
    /*
     * sort en group by
     */

    $luxury = array();
    $not_luxury = array();
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if ($value["MinimumRate"] > 500) {
            $luxury[] = $value;
        } else {
            $not_luxury[] = $value;
        }
    }

    $return = '<div id="no_luxury" >';

    foreach ($luxury as $value) {
        $return .= $value['Description'] . " : " . $value["MinimumRate"] . "<br />";
    }

    $return .= '</div>';

    $return .= '<div id="luxury" >';

    foreach ($luxury as $value) {
        $return .= $value['Description'] . " : " . $value["MinimumRate"] . "<br />";
    }

    $return .= '</div>';

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Your logic is reversed: `$value["MinimumRate"] < 500 -> $luxury` seems like a strange definition of luxury

Comment: Thx MitMaro, nice idea to use tenp array and store the values. One tiny thing, i replaced your first foreach so it read `$not_luxury as $value` btw how do set your answer as the answer??

Comment: Your welcome, To accept an answer just check the check mark below the rating of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is when MinimumRate = 500, you whould do:

```
if ($value["MinimumRate"] <= 500)    // this is your first 'if' in your code
```

or

```
if ($value["MinimumRate"] >= 500)    // this is the second 'if' in your code
```